# C++ send data size before sending data via TCP

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

Disclaimer: I am really new to this and so I will be as clear as I can.

I have a variable "packet" size of data. I know TCP is a streaming protocol - it streams bytes, not packets.

Now, I would like to tell my client the size of the data to read from the stream (which constitutes one of my 'packets').

The data that I am sending is in `std::string` format

If my string was called `outstring`, how could I populate `UINT8 buff[4]` with the size of my string that needs to be read on the client?

My client, written in C#, looks like this:

```
int total = 0;
int read;
byte[] datasize = new byte[4];

read = socket.Receive(datasize, 0, 4, 0);
int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(datasize, 0);
int dataleft = size;
byte[] data = new byte[size];

while (total < size) {
  read = socket.Receive(data, total, dataleft, 0);
  if (read == 0) {
    break;
  }
  total += read;
  dataleft -= read;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Apologies, this isn't a direct answer to your question, but it may be useful.

Programming with raw sockets sucks. There's a lot of work to do to make a program deal with them robustly. For example, in your code snippet you attempt to receive 4 bytes into datasize. There is no guarantee that that single socket.Receive() operation will actually read 4 bytes, it can read anything between 1 and 4 bytes. You have to call socket.Receive() in a loop until you have received all 4 bytes, just like you do later.

Fortunately there's things like [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) that take almost all of the pain away and give you a nice simple message passing framework layered on top of sockets, pipes, memory, etc. If you just want to get something done it comes highly recommended.

Comment: +1 You need to make a `readAll` function or something like that and use it instead of `read` if you're going to assume that it will either fail or read the number of bytes you asked it to read.

Comment: Comment, but too big for a comment and this really needs to be pointed out. Upvoted

Comment: Yes, it's one of the classics.   Needed saying.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, of course a readAll() function helps. But making that robust is a load of work in itself. There's a whole host of problems to deal with beyond looping to receive all the bytes that have been asked for. Writing a readAll() and dealing with all the possible problems is certainly an education!

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[0] = l & 0x000000ff;
byte[1] = (l & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
byte[2] = (l & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
byte[3] = (l & 0xff000000) >> 24;
```

this assumes you want it in little endian format. If you want bigendian

```
byte[3] = l & 0x000000ff;
byte[2] = (l & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
byte[1] = (l & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
byte[0] = (l & 0xff000000) >> 24;
```

Comment: Addendum: [Wiki page on Endinanness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) to help readers who are wondering, "Why in the name of Brainy Smurf's Glasses is pm100 putting himself through this bit-shifting hell?"

Comment: pm100 could do it with htonl and simply casting the int to byte* but this way seems clearer. Maybe not :-) And I was too lazy to lookup what c# bitconverter wanted :-(

Answer (score 0):

Your sending code is writing in C++, so you don't need a byte array at all, you can send the integer size value directly, eg:

```
uint32_t size = htonl(outstring.size()); // convert from host byte order to network byte order (big endian)
send(theSocket, (char*)&size, sizeof(size), 0);
send(theSocket, outstring.c_str(), outstring.size(), 0);
```

On the .NET client side, you can then do something like this:

```
bool readSocketFully(Socket s, byte[] buf)
{
    int idx = 0;
    int dataleft = buf.Length;
    int read;

    while (dataleft > 0) {
        read = s.Receive(buf, idx, dataleft, 0);
        if (read == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        idx += read;
        dataleft -= read;
    }
    return true;
}

byte[] readPacket(Socket s)
{
    byte[] datasize = new byte[4];    

    if (!readSocketFully(s, datasize)) {
        return null;
    }

    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) {
        System.Array.Reverse(datasize, 0, 4); // convert from network byte order (big endian) to host byte order (little endian)
    }
    int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(datasize, 0);
    byte[] data = new byte[size];

    if (size > 0) {
        if (!readSocketFully(socket, data)) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

```
byte[] data = readPacket(socket);
// use data as needed ...
```